Supremum Norm on Space of Continuous Functions
I don't get a uniform answer:
$$C = \{f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \text{$f$ continuous and $f(0)=0$} \}$$
is $||f||_\infty = sup_{x \in \mathbb R} |f(x)|$ a norm on C?
I think not: because f(x) = x, its supremum is $\infty$, so not part of $\mathbb R$, and thus no norm.
But as my book says $C[a,b]$ with supremum norm is a norm, I'm confused because isn't there continuous functions like $\tan(x)$ that also reach $\infty$?
edit:  so the operator $T: C \to \mathbb R, f \mapsto f(1)$ will not be continuous, because lack of a norm? Or am I wrong?

Because $[a, b]$ is compact which makes every function bounded whereas $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

@MadhanKumar Why are you giving an answer in the comment section?

@Arthur Can't I do that?

@MadhanKumar If you take a look at the comment box before you start typing, the gray text that's in it says you shouldn't. And it's bad for the site,  as it circumvents and dilutes the whole system of answered and unanswered questions.

@Arthur I have never noticed it. I'll take it in my mind text time.

@Arthur ... "Can't I do that?"  Yes, you can do it.  But now this question remains "unanswered" as far as the software is concerned.  You can also repeat your comment as an answer.

@MadhanKumar so the operator $T: C \to \mathbb R, f \mapsto f(1)$ will also not be continuous, because lack of a norm? Or am I wrong?

@jolr To talk about continuity we need topological space. In this case atleast we need normed linear space, Since $C$ is not well defined as a normed linear space we cannot talk about continuity.

The issue is that there are unbounded continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$, so there are elements of $C$ which are unbounded. As you stated in your question, the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := x$ is one such example. So an attempt to define a function $\|\cdot\|_{\infty} : C \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\|f\|_{\infty} := \sup\{|f(t)| : t\in \mathbb{R} \}$ fails because $\{|f(t)| : t\in \mathbb{R} \}$ is not bounded, and as a result $\sup\{|f(t)| : t\in \mathbb{R} \}$ will either not exist or will be equal to $\infty$, depending on whether you wish to work with the extended real numbers or not. In either case, there is no sensible way to define $\sup\{|f(t)| : t\in \mathbb{R} \}$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}$ when $f$ is unbounded.
However, there are certain restrictions you can place on the domain $D$ to ensure that all continuous functions $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous. One such condition is to require that $D$ is a closed and bounded non-trivial interval, so that it is of the form $[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$. Fixing such an interval, there is a result in real analysis which states that all continuous real-valued functions defined on the closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ are bounded. As a result, for each $f\in C[a,b]$, $\{|f(t)| : t\in [a,b] \}$ is a non-empty bounded subset of the real numbers, so $\sup\{|f(t)| : t\in [a,b] \}$ exists and consequently the function $\|\cdot\|_{\infty} : C[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\|f\|_{\infty} := \sup\{|f(t)| : t\in [a,b] \}$ is well-defined. Then it can be verified that $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is a norm on $C[a,b]$.
It is also worth mentioning that what prevented such a norm from being defined on $C$ was that there were unbounded functions which were elements of $C$. However, if you restrict the collection you are working with to the elements of $C$ which are bounded, which will be denoted by $BC$, then you are able to define a function $\|\cdot\|_{\infty} : BC \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\|f\|_{\infty} := \sup\{|f(t)| : t\in \mathbb{R} \}$, and it can be verified that this is a norm on $BC$.
Regarding your second question, it only makes sense to ask if $T$ is continuous if there is some kind of continuity structure on $C$, which is usually a topology on that set. If you don't have a norm defined on $C$ or don't have any topology defined on $C$, it doesn't make sense to talk about continuity and consequently to even talk about whether $T$ is continuous or not.
